# How would one say "to call on a student"?

Tags: verbs, word-requests

I would like to write a sentence to the effect of "the student was afraid to be called on." I have searched all over to find the verb of "calling on" a student and the best I can find is 当たる as [provided by this dictionary website](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BD%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B) (see definition 11).

However, I do know that this verb tends to mean "hit," and I am doubtful of how common 当たる would be used for this context of calling upon a student by a teacher.

Would this word be normally used in this way? Or is there a better, more common way to convey the idea of teachers calling upon a student to answer a question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use:

transitive 当てる for "(for a teacher) to call on a student to answer a question", and
intransitive 当たる for "(for a student) to be called on (by a teacher)".

We also use:

[指名]{しめい}する for "(for a teacher) to call on a student".

E.g.

> 「(生徒が)授業で当たる」
> 「(生徒が)授業で(先生に)当てられる」
> 「(先生が)授業で生徒を当てる」
> 「(先生が)生徒を指名する」
> 「(生徒が)授業で(先生に)指名される」

(当てる/当たる sounds a little more casual/conversational than 指名する/される.)